# Changing Android App Background Including Spinners and Dialogs

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-dialog, android-theme

I want to change default white background in my android app to another color.

I am using `android:background="#HEXCODE"` in my activity, it changes the background but the dialogs and spinners still have white background.

I also tried creating styles / custom theme but it changes the entire theme (the button and spinner style look like Androind 2.3 instead of ICS look and feel)

I don't want to change anything but on the background that is consistent also in spinners and dialogs.

Thanks.

**EDIT**
Style Code:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:background">#FFFFBB</item>
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
```

Comment: What theme are you using for your app?

Comment: Try changing your parent to `android:Theme.Holo.Light` and see if that fixes it.  That'll only work on 3.0 and up though.

Comment: @MCeley Thanks a lot for the suggestion. I gave it a try. Spinners look just I'd wish them to, but dialogs and headers looks incredibly bad now.. Color is not consistent, white spots here and there.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the color of the backgrounds of all widgets and the layout by

```
    android:background="@color/black">
```

in your values folder make a xml like this

```
  <resources>
      <color name="red">#ff0000</color> 
      <color name="green">#00ff00</color> 
      <color name="blue">#0000ff</color> 
      <color name="black">#000000</color> 
  </resources>
```

This worked for me.